# TYPO3 9.5: TCA type 'slug' always adds '-1' to URL

Tags: typo3, extbase, slug, typo3-9.x

I have the following configuration in my extbase TCA configuration:

```
'path_segment' => array(
  'exclude' => 1,
  'l10n_mode' => 'mergeIfNotBlank',
  'label' => 'Path Segment',
  'config' => [
  'type' => 'slug',
  'generatorOptions' => [
    'fields' => ['productname'],
    'replacements' => [
      '/' => '-',
      '.' => '',
      '®' => '',
      ',' => '',
      '|' => '',
      ' ' => '-',
    ],
  ],
  'fallbackCharacter' => '-',
  'eval' => 'unique'
]
),
```

When I save, I get URLs with `-1` added to the URL (f.e.g "myproduct-1" instead of just "myproduct")

I can only avoid this when clicking the Icon which is labled "Recalculate URL Segment from page title" in the List-Module when editing a record.

Our Editors do not mind much about this field and would change the URL every time they save the record.
What can I do to have this "recalculation" automatically" done? Or what am I doing wrong in my configuration? 
I'm using TYPO 3 9.5.17.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update to 9.5.18. This behaviour is a regression:

> 2020-05-14 ccd6da5027 [BUGFIX] Exclude current record when checking slug's uniqueness (thanks to Xavier Perseguers)

See [Release Notes](https://get.typo3.org/release-notes/9.5.18).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I will do that soon. For the first time I could help me out by changing the 'eval' from 'unique' to 'uniquiInPid'